# when -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Tags: objective-c, io, nsstring, nsmutablearray

I am getting the data from server like

```
listremainders (
        {
        Remainter = "2014-12-28T19:42:39";
        RemainterDate = "2014-12-04 10:24:57";
        RemainterID = 16;
        RemainterNotes = hjg;
    }
```

In that i am retrieving the “Remainter value”.
In console also it is displaying like
dateObj (
    "2014-12-28T19:42:39"
)

I wrote the code like this to retrieve the no.of dates from API.Here is my code…

```
datesArrayOfString = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *dic in (NSMutableArray *)dateObj) {

        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"];//date format cin
        NSDate *sDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dic];
       // NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterTwo = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE dd MMM"];
        NSString *dateSTring=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:sDate];
        [datesArrayOfString addObject:dateSTring];
    }

    NSLog(@"array of strings are %@", datesArrayOfString);
```

The App is crashing when the loop is happening.It is coming like….

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0227bdf6 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f05a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x021331e1 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 881
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02132e41 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 65
    4   TimeTableApp                        0x00184416 -[OneToOneViewController CallingListRemaindersServices] + 1926
    5   TimeTableApp                        0x0017da13 -[OneToOneViewController viewDidLoad] + 323
    6   UIKit                               0x00a46d54 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 771
    7   UIKit                               0x00a47045 -[UIViewController view] + 35
    8   UIKit                               0x00a5ab09 -[UIViewController _setPresentationController:] + 103
    9   UIKit                               0x00a535c9 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:presentationController:animationController:interactionController:completion:] + 848
    10  UIKit                               0x00a54368 -[UIViewController _presentViewController:withAnimationController:completion:] + 1741
    11  UIKit                               0x00a57032 __62-[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:]_block_invoke + 345
    12  UIKit                               0x00a56e84 -[UIViewController presentViewController:animated:completion:] + 224
    13  UIKit                               0x00fc3011 -[UIPopoverController _presentShimmedPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:] + 217
    14  UIKit                               0x00fc3211 -[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:] + 355
    15  TimeTableApp                        0x001067de -[TimeTableViewController collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:] + 61534
    16  UIKit                               0x01002dc8 -[UICollectionView _selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 591
    17  UIKit                               0x01020612 -[UICollectionView _userSelectItemAtIndexPath:] + 191
    18  UIKit                               0x01020806 -[UICollectionView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 492
    19  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f1b7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    20  UIKit                               0x00aa4b44 forwardTouchMethod + 270
    21  UIKit                               0x00aa4bb4 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 31
    22  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f1b7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    23  UIKit                               0x00aa4b44 forwardTouchMethod + 270
    24  UIKit                               0x00aa4bb4 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 31
    25  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f1b7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    26  UIKit                               0x00aa4b44 forwardTouchMethod + 270
    27  UIKit                               0x00aa4bb4 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 31
    28  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01f1b7cd -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    29  UIKit                               0x00aa4b44 forwardTouchMethod + 270
    30  UIKit                               0x00aa4bb4 -[UIResponder touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 31
    31  UIKit                               0x00d28257 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 13225
    32  UIKit                               0x0094171b -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1356
    33  UIKit                               0x0094257f -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 769
    34  UIKit                               0x00907aa9 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    35  UIKit                               0x009178de _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
    36  UIKit                               0x008ec079 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0219f7bf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x021952cd __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x02194828 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x021941ab CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x02193fdb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    42  GraphicsServices                    0x04c3924f GSEventRunModal + 192
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x04c3908c GSEventRun + 104
    44  UIKit                               0x008efe16 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    45  TimeTableApp                        0x0018f40d main + 141
    46  libdyld.dylib                       0x0314aac9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I don’t know why `sDate` is getting ‘nil’.But the data is coming in ‘dic’ but it is not storing in ‘sDate’.

What mistake i did?
Can anyone help to solve this one.I am new to Objective-c.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`

Comment: You should create and set the format of your two date formatters outside the loop.  And you should always check the result of `dateFromString` for nil.  And you can't insert a nil into an NSArray or NSDictionary.  And `T` needs to be single-quoted in a date format string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your api send you Array with Dictionary inside, so your loop must look like these:

```
for (NSDictionary *dictionary in NSArray)
{
    for (NSString *key in dictionary) 
    {
       id value = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

be careful to -dateFromString method, note that:

> **Return Value** A date representation of string interpreted using the
>   receiver’s current settings. If dateFromString: can not parse the
>   string, returns nil.

[Reference Apple Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html)

If you are not able to parse any entry, you should check the pattern indicated in dateFormat property, [see this](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1). Anyway, you should always check if the input date format match with your entry string because if the format does not match you'll get nil.

To avoid this, check if the sDate is not nil:

```
NSDate *sDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dic];
if (sDate != nil)
  ...
```